# Fixing homebrew path

Tags: macos, python, homebrew

I'm learning Python and most tutorials recommend to install Python using homebrew so I installed homebrew then I typed:

```
brew install python
```

which should overwrite OS X Python 2.7.10 with 2.7.11 but I think it didn't and when I enter:

```
brew doctor
```

I get:

> Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
>   formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
>   Consider setting the PATH for example like so
>       echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

What should I do? Should I uninstall everything and start over?

Answer (score 4):

It might be unrelated to the problem with Python, but at this moment, you should do exactly what the message says, i.e. type the following command:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After that reopen terminal session or run `. ~/.bash_profile` command.

It just says that some of the programs you installed with homebrew are placed in `/usr/local/sbin` directory, but your shell "does not know" about them.

For a reference you can check which programs (formulae) are there by listing the contents:

```
ls /usr/local/sbin
```

---

As for checking Python, type:

```
ls -l `which python`
```

It will give you the path to the current executable. You want it the output to look this way:

```
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  34 Dec 14 21:12 /usr/local/bin/python@ -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/python
```

Comment: the export command didn't work, brew doctor show same message even after restarting terminal session

Comment: entered export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile and hit enter

Comment: i entered brew doctor to check after i reopened the terminal and it shows the same message

Comment: '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'

Comment: it shows nothing..i opened it with texteditor and it was empty

Comment: .bash_profile now contains `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"`, wrong?

Comment: thanks it worked, but should't the .bash_profile contain only the path not `export PATH =` ?

Comment: it doesn't hurt